# django - test is_authenticated() in middleware instead of views

Tags: django

Most of my views require login.  Is there a way to specify that all views or a subset of views must have the user is_authenticated() =  True before proceeding.  If not, the user is redirected to a login page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want so, there are some rules that you must follow,

- `request.user` is set on `AuthenticationMiddleware`, so placing your custom middleware before that will fail.
- you can only use `process_view` method, which is executed before your view is called

But, somehow; you must make a kind of list like **login free views**, but that is not likely because checking the list everytime you create a new view might be problem. On the other hand, `login_required` decorator works just like that and it is easier to use... So you must think twice before doing a such thing and consider if you  **really** need something like that.

Here is the [doc for Custom Middlewares](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/middleware/) and here is the [django defalut middleware classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/middleware/) which is important because order of the middelware classes is really matters.